# unterminated string literal Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using the following code in php:

PHP:

```
 $suggested_sentence[0] = "Hello, how are you?";
  echo $suggested_sentence[0] . ' <input type="image" src="button.png" 
  onclick = update_textarea('. $textareacount.','. "'".$suggested_sentence[0]."')/>";
```

Javascript function:

```
function update_textarea(count, new_sentence) {
    document.getElementById('sentence' + count).value = new_sentence;
}
```

But when i press the button i get the error "unterminated string literal but if i change the value of `$suggested_sentence[0] = "Hello"` it works fine.

What should i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file after PHP has executed to ensure that your button looks like this...

```
<input type="image" src="button.png" onclick="update_textarea(1, 'Hello, how are you?');"/>
```

Note that the onclick event is surrounded with double-quotes.

You can adjust your example like this:

```
 $suggested_sentence[0] = "Hello, how are you?";
  echo $suggested_sentence[0] . ' <input type="image" src="button.png" 
  onclick="update_textarea('. $textareacount.', '. "'" . $suggested_sentence[0]."'" . ')"/>';
```

Comment: @fawad, glad I could help. Feel free to click on that tick next to the answer if it solved your problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

[HTML encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) `$suggested_sentence[0]` as it may contain characters that break the javascript literal (such as `'` so make sure you set `quote_style` to `ENT_QUOTES` for this).

Comment: This is a good suggestion, although not the culprit in this case.